# Clickable Texts in my page with background image

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

> I have a Problem,in my page i want to clickable some texts that i use above the background image,i use InkWell and GestureDetector even but both of them didnt work,i use them for background image even but they didnt work ,i Dont know how i solve it,plz help me

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(

  body: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[

        Image.asset('images/mainUiNew.jpg',
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
         width: double.infinity,
         fit:  BoxFit.cover,
         alignment: Alignment.center,),

      new Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.58, -0.7),
        child: new InkWell(
          child: new Text('Tracking',style: StyleTitle() ),
          onTap: () {
            print('hi');
          },
        ),
      ),

     new Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.49, -0.55),
        child: new InkWell(
          child: new Text('Track & Trace Your Package',style: StyleSubtitle()),
          onTap: () {
            var Router = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext){
              return new CustomLoginForm();
            });
            Navigator.of(context).push(Router);
          },
        ),
      ),
      new Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0.1,-0.1),
        child: new InkWell(
          child: new Text('OutBound',style: StyleTitle()),
          onTap: (){
            var Router = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext){
              return new OutBoundRate();
            });
            Navigator.of(context).push(Router);
          },
        ),
      ),
      new Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0.3, 0.02),
          child: new InkWell(
            child: new Text('Get OutBound Package Rate ',style: StyleSubtitle()),
            onTap: (){
              var Router = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext){
                return new OutBoundRate();
              });
              Navigator.of(context).push(Router);
            },
          )

      ),
      new Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.58,0.6),
          child: new InkWell(
            child: new Text('InBound',style: StyleTitle()),
            onTap: (){
              var Router = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext){
                return new InBoundRate();
              });
              Navigator.of(context).push(Router);
            },
          )
      ),
      new Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.49, 0.7),
          child: new InkWell(
            child: new Text('Get InBound Package Rate ',style:StyleSubtitle()),
            onTap: (){
              var Router = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext){
                return new InBoundRate();
              });
              Navigator.of(context).push(Router);
            },
          )

      ),
      new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new ExpandableListView(title: "Main Menu");
        },
        itemCount: 1,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: Container(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 100.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(60.0)),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(

              color: Colors.black54,
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
          )
        ],
        color: Colors.white,
    ),

    child: FittedBox(
      child: FloatingActionButton(


        backgroundColor: Color(0xffffcd05),
          child: Padding(

            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Image.asset("images/logo-express.png",height:200.0,width: 300.0,

            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            var Router = new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext){
              return new FirstPage();
            });
            Navigator.of(context).push(Router);
          }),

    ),
   //shape:
   //        icon: new Icon(Icons.add,
   //        color: Color(0xffd4351c),),

   // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0),)),
   // child: Image.asset("images/logo-express.png",height:200.0,width: 400.0,),

  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    //clipBehavior:Clip.antiAlias,
    color: Color(0xffd4351c),
     //shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
         //SizedBox(width: double.infinity, height: 70.0,),
        Material(
          child: SizedBox(
           // width: double.infinity,
            height: 60.0,),
          color: Color(0xffd4351c),
        ),
       // SizedBox(),
        FlatButton.icon(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(context, SlideRightRoute(page: ContactUs()));
        },
          icon: Icon(Icons.phone_in_talk,color:Colors.white,),
          label: new Text('Contact Us',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),),

        FlatButton.icon(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(context, SlideLeftRoute(page: AboutUs()));
        },
          icon: Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.white,),
          label: new Text('About US',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0 , 0.0, 0),),
      ],

    )
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to use the `GestureDetector` widget?

Comment: i used it ,but didnt work

Comment: Without seeing your image, I'm not sure why you want to use `Stack`. Are you aligning the clickable areas with parts of the image? Why can't you use `Columns` and `Rows` to build your view?

Comment: without background image it didnt work even,i use Stack because i have just an image for background and some Texts above it and every text navigate to a cerain page,even i clear stack and just use a text and test it but it didnt word

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you have?

Comment: I found it,it is because of using Listview.builder in this page,but i need to use it,how i can solve this problem???

Comment: you can use Container instead of Stack and add decoration then DecorationImage and you'll get your background then use Column or Rows for your text but if you want to use Stack Wrap your Stack inside a container then add height and width to it

Comment: I have a fullscreen accordion menu with a few clicks. When I use this menu on a page, other clicks do not work in the body.     here is a screenshop of my app :https://i.stack.imgur.com/aakgw.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i need was shrinkWrap = true inside ListView.builder.

Else the children will wont know how much space to take in the scrollable widget.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stack you should use positioned widget instead of Align and use gesturedetector
For Gesture detector use the following code:

```html
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print("onTap called.");
  },
  child: Text("foo"),
),
```

it will work instead of inkwell.

Comment: I use Position instead of Align and  use gesturedetector ,but i didint work ,in floatingActionButton and in my menu i use inkwell or gesturedetector they work but in main body they dont work,i dont know why

Comment: hi samane, I think you should use a container as a parent and then use a stack layout widget on it, use this approach, it may work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Stack:

```
return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     child: Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
        *your children here*
       ]
     )
   )
);
```

but I suggest using this:

```
return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       image: DecorationImage(
         image: NetworkImage(*image_url*) or you can use AssetImage(*asset_path*),
         fit: BoxFit.cover
       )
     ),
     child: Row/Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           *your children here*
        ]
     )
   )
);
```